# Is it possible to disable the left and right arrow keys in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, horizontal-scrolling, arrow-keys

In listboxes in Tkinter, the left and right arrow keys can be used to scroll the content in the `listbox` if it extends past the size of the box itself.

I've attempted rebinding the key using the `.bind()` function, however no matter what I have it do the scrolling functionality is still present.

I also tried using `[the listbox].xview_moveto(0.0)` to override the scroll, but 0.0 for some reason is not technically the beginning of the `listbox`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A return value of "break" will stop any further functions, so you have to rebind it to a function that returns "break".

```
.bind("<Left>", lambda e: "break") # Disables the left arrow key
```

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot mate. I read over the documentation for both listboxes and events, did I miss it or were you aware of this previously?

Edit: I missed it in the documentation. Wow I'm blind.

Comment: Does this mean left arrow key cannot be binding with any other widget?

Comment: @CoolCloud no, this only affects the widget that it's bound to.

Comment: Weird enough, I binded this to listbox and then I couldnt use it on my root window .